# The semantic security in Anonymous Hierarchical identity-bases encryption?

Tags: identity-based-encryption, anonymity

In Anonymous Hierarchical Identity-Based Encryption (Without Random Oracles) by Boyen, to prove security it defined challenge ciphertext like
[image]

I actually can't get how does the proof work? Why we should define challenge ciphertext like this?